# ATTENTION!This page does not represent the entire state of the ethereum network - listing a node on this page is a voluntary process

Tags: blockchain

I am trying to attach my private blockchain to ethstats. When i run the npm, it gives me this error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not an error, this a note. Which problems do you face? Which node do you run? Which npm package do you execute? Can you post an excerpt of the console output?

Comment: I have the output of console to the question.

Comment: I solved this issue by using 'grunt all' command.  The link to the whole procedure is "https://github.com/cubedro/eth-netstats".